# Methods, arguments, and member variables, not accessible in Windows to Mono port

Tags: c#, mono

I can't find this addressed on SO. I am porting a Windows .NET application, that compiles and runs perfectly, to Mono on Linux. I have missed something small. Here is a part of the code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DAPTimeClock
{
    public static class DatabaseOps
    {
        private static string _dbFile;

        public static string Get_dbFile()
        {
            return _dbFile;
        }

        public void Set_dbFile(string value)
        {
            this._dbFile = value;
        }

        public static bool foundFile = false;

        public static string SetFile(String dblocation = @"Data" +
                         "Source=../db/TimeClock.db; Version=3;")
        {
            Set_dbFile( dblocation );
            int pathStart = Get_dbFile().IndexOf ('=') + 1;
            int pathEnd = Get_dbFile().IndexOf (";") - 1;
            string filePath = Get_dbFile().Substring (pathStart, 
            pathEnd - pathStart + 1);

            if (File.Exists (filePath)) {
                foundFile = true;
                return string.Format ("The db file {0} has been " +
                                 "located",  filePath);                      
            } else 
            {
                foundFile = false;
                return string.Format("Unable to find db file {0}.", 
                                    filePath);
            }
        }

        public static bool AddPerson(Person p)
        {
            bool result = false;

   Class Continues .....
```

Here are the issues:

- Other classes can't find any methods from this class. ex. DatabaseOp.Set_dbFile()  Yields no such method.
- The methods in this class can't find methods from this class.
- The methods in this class can't see the outside classes.
- If I pass an argument to the methods in the class, the complier says it can't find a parameter by that name.
- The methods in the class can't see its own member variables.

I have done the following:

- I removed the static, now making regular objects.  (no change)
- I double checked the namespaces. (all the same, no typos)
- I tried making the member variable public and adding a get; and set;

I am stumped.  Can anyone see what might be hanging this up? Is there something about mono I missed? All other classes are working fine.

Comment: I doubt the problem is in the code. Maybe a problem with your mono installation?

Comment: But then why would the numerous other classes behave correctly.  I did try a complete remove and reinstall as suggested and the behavior did not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set_dbFile should be declared as

```
   public static void Set_dbFile(string value)
```

compiler should complain: "cannot declare instance members in static class". Have you miss this?

Comment: Thanks, I missed that and you are correct.  Many more thanks.